# Using concat in C without string library functions or array notation

Tags: c, concatenation

My task is to be able to concat two string and return a new string using pointers. It is supposed to return a new string but it returns a blank space currently. Here is my code:

```
char* concat(char* first, char* second){
    int string1Len = strlen(first);
    int string2Len = strlen(second);
    int length = string1Len + string2Len;
    char* string = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
    int i;
    while(i < string1Len){
        *(string + i) = *first;
        first+= 1;
        i+= 1;
    }
    while( i < length){
        *(string + i) = *second;
        second+= 1;
        i+= 1;
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: `i` is not initialized to `0`.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio that not the only error...

Comment: @Stargateur what other error do you see? Perhaps he missed `NULL` to terminate the string?

Comment: Can you add the call to `concat` and the definition of its args?

Comment: Remember that `strlen()` does not count the null byte that terminates a string, and that you must allocate space for the null byte, and set the last byte to zero before returning.  Also, `malloc()` can fail — you should check the return value.

Comment: But `strlen()` is a part of the string library.

Comment: regarding these three statements: `int string1Len = strlen(first);
    int string2Len = strlen(second);
    int length = string1Len + string2Len;`  the function: `strlen()` returns the index to the NUL byte (and indexes in C, start at 0) so the addition of the two returned values from `strlen()` will be 1 char too small I.E. no room for the trailing NUL byte

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and in the call to `malloc()` is just cluttering the code.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: the variable is not initialized so contains what ever trash that is on the stack at that location.   Also, strongly suggest using (instead of `while()`)  `for(  i=0; i< string1len; i++ ) {...}` etc.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio, in general, when mentioning NUL the discussion is about the character `'\0'.  When mentioning NULL (note the 2 `L`s) the discussion is about the (size of a pointer) value (char *0)

Comment: the posted code is using `strlen()` which is a string function, so does not adhere to the criteria of not using any string functions.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the unitialized `int i = 0`, your code seems fine. This worked on my machine:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* concat(char* first, char* second){
    int string1Len = strlen(first);
    int string2Len = strlen(second);
    int length = string1Len + string2Len;
    char* string = malloc(sizeof(char)*length + 1);
    assert(string);
    int i=0;
    while(i < string1Len){
        string[i] = *first;
        first+= 1;
        i+= 1;
    }
    while(i < length){
        string[i] = *second;
        second += 1;
        i += 1;
    }
    string[i] = '\0';
    return string;
}

int main(){
        char* x = "foo";
        char* y = "bar";
        printf("%s\n", concat(x, y));
        // prints 'foobar'
}
```

**P.S.** use `string[i]` instead of `*(string + i)`, it's generally considered more readable.

Comment: `size_t` is automatically converted to `int` via casting. I previously commented about the `NULL` byte but none of my tests failed, even with empty strings.

Comment: Overflow on `int` is undefined behavior, and `size_t` generally hold bigger value than `int` there is not good reason to use an `int` in this case. For your second point, "Testing shows the presence, not the absence of bugs" - Dijkstra (1969)

Comment: The test shown leaks memory. You should try freeing memory, and run some loops with different sizes of strings so that the memory is probably reused.  You don't null terminate your string (and `NULL` is not necessarily the same as a null byte, `'\0'`  — it is often `((void *)0)` which generates warnings when used in an assignment to a `char`). The use of `size_t` vs `int` doesn't leave me panic-stricken; for many purposes, using `int` will be fine — but truly robust code might care about using `size_t` and checking for overflows (though they're very unlikely).  OTOH, using `size_t` isn't hard.

Comment: I agree with you guys, I really do. But the op is clearly at his first steps in C programming and debating about `size_t` and `int` seems unreasonable to me.

Comment: Using `assert(first != 0 && second != 0);` to check the arguments would be reasonable — the interface definition implies that two valid strings should be passed and if either pointer is null, it is not valid.  Using `assert(string)` to check the return value from `malloc()` is not good — that is a runtime error that the calling code cannot control, necessarily.  It would be better to use `if (string == 0) return 0;` (or spell `0` as `NULL` — your choice) or equivalent.  That way, the calling code can control what happens on error, but your code works as best it can even in the face of error.

Comment: There is an element of 'best practice' in that discussion — but showing best practices is often helpful to beginners.

Comment: Man, I see your points. The fact is, I give the op an answer I think he can understand. I would never write code like that. If you don't like my answer, then downvote it.

Comment: `sizeof(char)*length + 1` is curious.  `sizeof(char)` is not needed as it is always 1.  If code is to remain with the cast, then it should be coded `sizeof(char)*(length + 1)` as the size should multiply the sum.

Comment: the function: `malloc()` expects all its' parameter to be `size_t`.  The returned value from: `strlen()` is `size_t`, so, overall, ALL the numeric values should be `size_t`   The compiler 'can' automatically convert the number types, but it should not have to and (with gcc) using the option: `-Wconversion` will allow the compiler to output warning messages about those 'automatic' conversions.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio, rather than debating, 1) refer the OP to the MAN page for the used functions.  2) when writing an answer, a) properly handle any errors and b) write the code correctly, so the OP learns early, the correct way to write the code. Also, for large values, (or negative values) casting `int` to `size_t` will invert the sign, which is a very bad idea

Comment: you had to add the `+1` to the parameter to `malloc()` and NUL terminate the concatenated string, so your statement: "other than....your code seems fine' is not correct

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

// You should use char const * as your function don't need to change the character of your input string
char *concat(char const *first, char const *second) { // put * on the variable name not the type
    assert(first && second); // test only include for debug build concat expect valid string
    size_t first_len = strlen(first); // strlen() return a size_t
    size_t second_len = strlen(second);
    // you could check for overflow case here
    size_t length = first_len + second_len; // malloc take a size_t as argument
    char *string = malloc(length + 1); // don't forget the nul terminate byte, sizeof(char) == 1
    if (!string) { // don't forget to check malloc() error
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t i = 0; // don't forget to initialize your variable
    while (*first) {
        string[i++] = *first++; // use [] notation is more readeable  in that case
    }
    while (*second) {
        string[i++] = *second++;
    }
    string[i] = '\0'; // never forget the nul terminate byte
    return string;
}

int main(void) {
    char *my_amazing_new_string = concat("Stack ", "Overflow");
    if (!my_amazing_new_string) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s", my_amazing_new_string);
    free(my_amazing_new_string);
}
```

Comment: I think your answer would be better with running text (or bullet points) to highlight the key changes.  The code looks solid though.  It might be possible to add `assert(first != 0 && second != 0)`, but that's not really necessary.

Comment: Also `first` and `second` can be declared `const` (if we're in improving-the-code mood)

Comment: Question title says "Without using array notation"

Comment: @weston This don't make sense. I don't care about a stupid homework rule. If OP want write `*(string + i++)` in place of `string[i++]`, I don't care. This doesn't matter in this question.

Answer (score 1):

**String** Libraries? I never use them :P

```
char * concat(char * dest, const char * src)
{
    // creates a pointer to `dest` so we can return it from from its start position.
    char * ptr = dest;          
    // increment dest until the null-terminated which is 0 (false//loop stops).
    while (*dest) dest++;   
    // so we assign dest pointer to src pointer while incrementing them.    
    while (*dest++ = *src++);   
    // return the `dest` pointer.
    return ptr;                 
}
```

Note that you'll need to allocate the first parameter yourself cause this function does concat the `dest` pointer itself, So the return value (is **Optional** ^^).

I also noticed that for some reason... everyone's allocating memory in the function itself, so I did my **2nd** version. However, it's not like 1st one (You'll need the return value though).

```
char * concat(char * s1, const char * s2)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    // length of s1.
    while (*s1++) i++;
    size_t s1_len = i; i = 0;
    s1 -= s1_len + 1;
    // length of s2.
    while (*s2++) i++;
    size_t s2_len = i; i = 0;
    s2 -= s2_len + 1;
    // allocates memory.
    char * newStr = (char *)malloc((s1_len + s2_len)+1); // +1 is for the nul-terminated character.
    if(!newStr) return newStr; // if malloc fails, return (null) pointer.
    // points to position 0 of the 1st string.
    char * ptr = newStr;
    // copies the content of s1 to the new string
    while (*ptr++ = *s1++);
    // get back to the null-terminated to overwrite it.
    *ptr--;
    // concentrate
    while (*ptr++ = *s2++);
    // return the `newStr` pointer.
    return newStr;                  
}
```

Comment: Why +2? Everyone else has a +1

Comment: Curious mixed use of `int` and `size_t`.  Suggest only `size_t`.

Comment: @chux I'd approve it of course since we're not dealing with negatives. Before I post this, I was writing the algorithm differently which needed the type of `int` (for other tasks than size). Thanks btw.

Comment: You should test for memory allocation failure and return NULL gracefully instead of invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie malloc returns `NULL` on fail, If `newStr` was `NULL`, There's no UB in this, The program will just crash before it even return from the function for trying to modify a `NULL` pointer (SegFault). I added the Exception.

Comment: @KiraSama: dereferencing a null pointer is definitely UB: it may crash as you assume or not crash on some non protected architectures... testing this condition and returning `NULL` is needed for defined operation.

Comment: @chqrlie You've got a point there. I should not assume that my code would run on a protected-mode OS. Since there's a **real-mode** at this level, It's a UB. I think I faced this kind of weird UB building a kernel before (little mistake, Big fail. I moved to PM though). Yup, I did add the exception for the defined operation, so the programmer can check if it fails before processing.

Comment: @KiraSama: the very concept of undefined behavior is once you have it, the program can fail in unpredictable ways, including no signs of failure at all! If you are lucky, the failure will be a crash that may be easy to investigate with a debugger, but can cause irreparable damage on the field, such as crashing the Mars lander. Do not rely on the OS protection to catch such problems, test the allocation failure and either gracefully exit the program with a diagnostic or return `NULL` and let the caller handle the condition appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code errors

#### Index not initialized

```
// int i;
int i = 0;
```

#### No null character appended nor allocated

```
// char* string = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
char* string = malloc(length + 1);
....
*(string + i) ='\0'; // add this
return string;
```

---

Minor stuff

#### sizeof(char) is always 1

```
//char* string = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
char* string = malloc(length);  // Also +1 as noted above
```

#### `int` may be too narrow

```
// int i;
size_t i;
```

#### Can't use `strlen()`

"without string library functions"

#### Allocation lacks check

```
char* string = malloc(...);
if (string == NULL) {  // add
  return NULL;
}
```

#### As source strings are not modified, use `const`.

This allows greater use of the function and potential optimizations.

```
//char* concat(char* first, char* second){
char* concat(const char* first, const char* second){
```

---

Some untested alternative code.   Note no integer variables.

```
char* concat(const char* first, const char* second) {
  const char *p1 = first;
  while (*p1) {
    p1++;
  }
  const char *p2 = second;
  while (*p2) {
    p2++;
  }
  char* string = malloc((p1 - first) + (p2 - second) + 1);
  if (string) {
    char *ps = string;
    while ((*ps = *first++)) {
      ps++;
    }
    while ((*ps = *second++)) {
      ps++;
    }
  }
  return string;
}
```